# Question about differential operators

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-operators

Say $N = ab$. How can I express $\frac{d}{dN}$ in terms of $\frac{d}{da}$ and $\frac{d}{db}$?

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a function $f=f(ab)$, then
$$\frac{df}{dN}=\frac{df}{da}\cdot \frac{da}{dN}+\frac{df}{db}\cdot \frac{db}{dN}
\\ =\frac{df}{da}\cdot \frac{1}{b}+\frac{df}{db}\cdot \frac{1}{a}$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dN}=\frac{1}{b}\cdot \frac{d}{da}+\frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{d}{db}$$